# adding big and dynamic org chart in gwt

Tags: java, gwt, graph, orgchart

I need to add to my GWT site a dynamic org chart which:

1. List item
2. can handle large number of nodes.
3. can be changed dynamically, e.g. selecting a specific node will draw it's children in case they were hidden. (preferably without redrawing the whole graph)
4. a small orientation window would be great.
5. nodes have to be clickable.

I'm now using [OrgChart](http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.1/com/google/gwt/visualization/client/visualizations/OrgChart.html) and I have many problems with it, e.g. in Explorer it shows maximum ~100 nodes (because of the table column limitation in tables). When I add a node, I need to refresh the whole chart causing the user to lose orientation and some more.

What should I use to be able to create it?

Comment: Recently I've been implementing interactive timeline in gwt. We used canvas for drawing background and SVG graphics for interactive elements. Pluses of SVG: perfect scalable graphics, can attach event handlers directly to svg elements, and easy to manipulate.